# How to handle java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending occuring in com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser?

Tags: java, apache, multipartform-data

**Environment**: - Jboss EAP 6.3 Alpha 1

**JDK**: - JDK 1.7 u_80 64 bit

We have a program functionality which is absolutely working fine in JDK 1.6 u_32 64 bit. Once we upgraded it to JDK 1.7 u_80 64 bit, it started throwing exception message **"Corrupt form data: premature ending"**. Following file is using in program http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/servlets/cos/05Nov2002/cos-05Nov2002.jar

It is quiet critical to find cause and solution of the problem because problem is varying in JDK 1.6 u_32 64 bit and  JDK 1.7 u_80 64 bit. But from the trace, it seems that problem clearly belongs to com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser.(MultipartParser.java:205)

On printing stack trace, we found following exception: -

```
java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending
       at com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser.<init>(MultipartParser.java:205)
       at org.apache.jsp.webaccess.configurations.adddocument.closeadddoc_jsp._jspService(closeadddoc_jsp.java:995)
       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
MultipartRequest multi = new MultipartRequest(request, "C:\\Users\\HP\\workspace\\Project_OnlineExa\\WebContent");
```

Should Be the first line of Servlet